# Upgrading Visual Studio 2015 RC to Visual Studio 2015 makes Cordova app incompatible

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I created a Windows Cordova app in Visual Studio 2015 RC. VS required me to update to the current full release. After doing so my app now says "This project is incompatible with the current edition of Visual Studio."

Comment: Why didn't you upgrade to rtm? RC won't get any new versions of Cordova and is already very old (we've shipped 4 updates since rtm). Plus, there are lots of fixes in newer versions. I recommend moving to rtm. (Disclosure: I work for Microsoft)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [migration](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/migrate-to-vs2015/) article for how to resolve this problem.